# Calabash iOS does not run after update

Tags: xamarin, calabash, calabash-ios

After last Calabash update I am not able to run test anymore. I use:

- calabash-cucumber-0.10.2
- run_loop-1.0.8
- ruby-2.1.0
- Xcode 6.0.1
- and Xamarin Calabash component (Xamarin Test Cloud Agent 10.1.1)

When I try to run tests I get:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:688:in `enable_accessibility_in_sim_data_dir'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:292:in `block in enable_accessibility_on_sims'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:291:in `map'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:291:in `enable_accessibility_on_sims'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/core.rb:95:in `run_with_options'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/run_loop-1.0.8/lib/run_loop/core.rb:687:in `run'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:718:in `block in new_run_loop'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in `times'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in `new_run_loop'
  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.10.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:597:in `relaunch'
  /Users/user/Projects/CalabashTest/features/support/01_launch.rb:27:in `Before'
```

In "`calabash-ios sim acc`" or "`calabash-ios console`" when I try to run `start_test_server_in_background` I'm getting the same error.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reverting to `ruby 2.0.0p481`.